# Is is possible to capture Amazon Lex's prompts in lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lex

I'm interested in logging the entirety of the conversation between my users and the Lex bot.

Currently, I can capture the user's responses using the validation/fulfillment lambda, but how can I capture the prompts that Lex gives to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to:

**(A)** set up a proxy between Lex and the output channels to capture what Lex delivers to the user. Use [Amazon Lex PostText API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) in the proxy to send and receive with Lex, then build your own channel connections with the proxy too.

Or

**(B)** build **all** of your response messages in Lambda and force Lex to use them, but this means you don't use `Delegate` nor the Lex Console prompts (even though you'll need prompts written in the console).

Comment: Interesting. It would be so much easier if they'd just pass along the previous Lex prompt in the request object!

Comment: I agree. I've had to create tracking of these things in sessionAttributes, including `last_elicit_slot` and `last_intent` and `last_prompt` myself. Would be nice if those were built in.